# How much is a dram and talent during Medo-Persian period?

Tags: ezra

We find in Ezra:

> KJV Ezra 8
>   27 Also twenty basons of gold, of a thousand drams; and two vessels of fine copper, precious as gold.

1. How much is a dram?
2. Was there a change in the measure of talent through various periods of history?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://biblehub.com/topical/t/talent.htm

> 1. (v. t.) Among the ancient Greeks, a weight and a denomination of money equal to 60 minae or 6,000 drachmae. The Attic talent, as a
>      weight, was about 57 lbs. avoirdupois; as a denomination of silver
>      money, its value was 243 15s. sterling, or about USD1,180.
> 2. (v. t.) Among the Hebrews, a weight and denomination of money. For silver it was equivalent to 3,000 shekels, and in weight was equal to
>      about 93/ lbs. avoirdupois; as a denomination of silver, it has been
>      variously estimated at from 340 to 396 sterling, or about USD1,645 to
>      USD1,916. For gold it was equal to 10,000 gold shekels.

According to  https://biblehub.com/topical/d/dram.htm

> 1. (n.) A weight; in Apothecaries' weight, one eighth part of an ounce, or sixty grains; in Avoirdupois weight, one sixteenth part of
>      an ounce, or 27.34375 grains.
> 2. (n.) A minute quantity; a mite.

Other references are available on the same web site.

Comment: A shekel would have had a constant value - 20 gerahs(Lev 27:25). Whether silver or gold, I don't see it changing based on material since it's a measure of weight(2Sa 14:26, Ezek. 4:10); likewise also would be the talent, being 3000 shekels as deduced from Ex. 38.

Answer (score -2):

Ezra doesn't mention dram or talent, instead it mentions daric = 8.4 grams and mina = 571 grams.

The English Standard Version gives the correct translations in Ezra 2:69 + 8:27.

During the reign of Cyrus the Great the daric coin didn't yet exist. Which suggests Koresh of Ezra 1 is Cyrus the Great's grandson and  namesake Xerxes rather then Cyrus the Great himself.

Comment: You should quote a source and reference for these assertions